# I want to check if cnic already exist it never insert the cnic

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

THis is another pattern  but it also have errors

DECLARE
DCNIC varchar(50);

```
BEGIN
 DCNIC :='';
    Select count(*) into DCNIC from EMPLOYEE where CNIC=:P36_CNIC;
    if DCNIC = 0
    then 
   insert into EMPLOYEE(CNIC) values (DCNIC);
    else
    DCNIC := 1;
    end if;
RETURN DCNIC;
END;
```

Comment: Is it MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: It's Sql query but it have so many mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Please change your Query 1 to this:

```
DECLARE
DCNIC VARCHAR(50)
DCNIC :=0;

BEGIN

    if not exists (Select * from EMPLOYEE where CNIC=:P36_CNIC)
    then 
  insert into EMPLOYEE(CNIC) values (DCNIC);
END;
```

Comment: ORA-06550: line 1, column 106: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following: ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval date <a string literal with character set specification> <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character s            This error is raised

Comment: DECLARE
DCNIC varchar(50);

    BEGIN
     DCNIC :='';
        Select count(*) into DCNIC from EMPLOYEE where CNIC=:P36_CNIC;
        if DCNIC = 0
        then 
       insert into EMPLOYEE(CNIC) values (DCNIC);
        else
        DCNIC := 1;
        end if;
    RETURN DCNIC;
    END;           THis is another pattern  but it also have errors

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to have a `unique` constraint (or index) on the column.  So:

```
alter table employee add constraint unq_employee_cnic on employee(cnic);
```

Then, just do the `insert`.  It will fail if the constraint is violated.  If necessary, you might want to catch the exception when it fails.

Why is this the correct way?  First, having the database enforce data integrity is allowing the database to do what it is designed to do.

Second, your code introduces race conditions.  Two different threads could both run the `if`, see that a given `cnic` value is not in the table, and then *both* could insert it.  You would have duplicates in that case.

Third, your code protects against one particular `insert`.  However, somewhere else in the code may be another `insert` that doesn't follow this logic.  And, no check is done.  Or, someone could decide that they want to "fix" the data and accidentally insert duplicates.

Fourth, your code protects against *inserts*. But `update`s can also introduce duplicate values.

Let the database do the work for you.